# Surfaces of revolution which are also ruled surfaces.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have been struggling to solve the following problem: "Determine all surfaces of revolution which are also ruled surfaces (in $\mathbb{R}^3$)."

Local parameterisations of ruled surfaces take the form $x(u,v) = \alpha(v)+u\beta(v) $ for regular smooth curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Local parameterisations of surfaces of revolution take the form $x(u,v) = (f(v)cos(u), f(v)sin(u), g(v))$ for smooth functions $f(v)$, $g(v)$ such that the curve $(f(v), 0, g(v))$ is regular and $f(v) \neq 0$.

I have tried using coefficients of the First Fundamental Form, but with little success. For example I know that for surfaces of revolution $F = 0$, which yields that $\alpha' \cdotp \beta = 0$ for the ruled surface if we take $\beta$ parameterised by arc-length, but this doesn't take me far.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple: since the surface is ruled, it contains a line $L$ (which is neither orthogonal to nor identical with the axis or rotation, since rotating such a line yields a degenerate 'surface'). Now since the surface is a surface of revolution, it contains all instances of the line $L$ rotated around the axis; actually, by rotating the line we already sweep the whole surface of revolution. One could argue that there may be another line $K$ which is not contained in the surface sweeped by the rotating $L$, but this would just add another surface of revolution (around the same axis) sweeped by the rotating line $K$; here we aim to describe only 'indecomposable' ruled surfaces of revolution.

We conclude that the 'indecomposable' ruled surfaces of revolution are: the (infinite) circular cylinder, the (double) circular cone, the circular hyperboloid of one sheet.

Comment: Thanks for this! However how do you conclude from the argument you gave that the ruled surfaces of revolution are the three you described? I sort of see it but not quite. :)

Comment: @Nao - If the line $L$ is parallel to the axis of rotation, we get a cylinder. If the line $L$ intersects the axis, we get a cone. In the remaining case the line $L$ sweeps out a hyperboloid of one sheet. This question is tagged "differential-geometry"; however, it is all geometry, without any differential in sight. You tried the differential geometry approach and ran into the wall; differential geometry was a red herring.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now! A very simple and elegant answer - thanks a lot.